# Getting more that one value

Tags: javascript, html

Can't think of a good title sorry!
What does it do!
I have ajson file looks a bit like this "You tired of https://google.com/index.html \n\n why not try https://bing.com/index.html"

What I would like it to do is make the text a click link DONE
Have the text displayed on the page just to be the domain of the url
eg google.com

I have it working to a point. It fine at getting the first url all formatted correctly but not the second one.

```js
var url = "You tired of https://google.com/index.html \n\n why not try https://bing.com/index.html ";
linkify(url);
    function linkify(url) {
        
        alert(url);
        
            var domain;
            //find & remove protocol (http, ftp, etc.) and get domain
            if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
                domain = url.split('/')[2];
            }
            else {
                domain = url.split('/')[0];
            }

            //find & remove port number
            domain = domain.split(':')[0];
        alert(domain);
   
      var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3;

        //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
       replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
        replacedText = url.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">'+domain+'</a>');

        //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
       replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
        replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">'+domain+'</a>');

        //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
        replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim;
      replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');

        
       document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = replacedText;}
```

```html
<span id="out"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've already solved your problem. But I figure I'd post my solution anyway. Who knows, you may like it more. Hope it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/90m6ss8b/2/

```
    var url = "You tired of https://google.com/index.html \n\n why not try https://bing.com/index.html ";
linkify(url);

function linkify(url) {
  var matches = url.match(/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm);

  alert(matches);

  for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    if (matches[i].indexOf("://") > -1) {
      alert(matches[i]);
      matches[i] = matches[i].split('/')[2];
      alert(matches[i]);
    }
  }

  alert(matches);

  var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3;
  replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/im;
  replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/im;
  replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/im;

  replacedText = replaceIndex(url, replacePattern1,'<a href="$1" target="_blank">' + matches[0] + '</a>');
  replacedText = replaceIndex(replacedText, replacePattern2,'$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">' + matches[0] + '</a>');
  replacedText = replaceIndex(replacedText, replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>'); 
  replacedText = replaceIndex(replacedText, replacePattern1,'<a href="$1" target="_blank">' + matches[1] + '</a>');
  replacedText = replaceIndex(replacedText, replacePattern2,'$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">' + matches[1] + '</a>');
  replacedText = replaceIndex(replacedText, replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');

  function replaceIndex(string, pattern, repl) {
    return string.replace(pattern, function(match, i) {
      if (i === match) return repl;
      return match;
    });
  }

  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = replacedText;
}
```

Comment: It works well. Thanks, but when the number of link are different  from post to post it can be a bit hit or miss. I know I can just change [1] to [2] and so on. Your way is more structured mine is more of a bodge job.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var url = "You tired of https://google.com/index.html \n\n why not try https://bing.com/index.html ";
    linkify(url);
    function linkify(url) {


        var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3, i;

        //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
        replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
        replacedText = url.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" class="urlcouint" target="_blank" id="xurl">$1</a>');

        //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
        replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
        replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$1</a>');

        //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
        replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim;
        replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');


        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = replacedText;}
   
        var nubero = ($('a.urlcouint').length);
        for(var i = 0; i < nubero; i++) {
            var domain, url;
            url = document.getElementById('xurl').href;
        //find & remove protocol (http, ftp, etc.) and get domain
        if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
            domain = url.split('/')[2];
        }
        else {
            domain = url.split('/')[0];
        }

        //find & remove port number
        domain = domain.split(':')[0];
        alert(domain);
        document.getElementById('xurl').innerHTML = domain;
        document.getElementById('xurl').setAttribute('id', 'xurldone');}
```

```html
<span id="out"></span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```